# Why Blazor app showing an error with any page reload

Tags: c#, blazor

I am working on project with Blazor technology. I need sometimes to use some JS code, and I need to include diffirant js files with each page, and as I know the only way to do it is adding it using JS function and Blazor JS invoke. So what I did is:
in _Host.razor

```
function addScriptFile(fileName){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script.setAttribute("src", file);
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(script);
}
```

Then in each page (component):

```
@inject IJSRuntime Js;
@functions{
    protected override async void OnAfterRender()
    {
        await Js.InvokeAsync<object>("addScriptFile","~/js/myFile.js");
    }
}
```

*It is working good, but the problem happening if the page has been reloaded. It throws an error
System.InvalidOperationException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being prerendered and the page has not yet loaded in the browser or because the circuit is currently disconnected. Components must wrap any JavaScript interop calls in conditional logic to ensure those interop calls are not attempted during prerendering or while the client is disconnected.*

What I understand from this error, that I am trying to invoke some javascript code before render completed. So I have used IComponentContext to make sure that the server is connected.
In my journey to fixing this issue, I have created a new Blazor project without any JS files, but it throws the same error on reloading page

I tried to make this:

```
@inject IComponentContext ComponentContext
@functions{
    protected override void OnAfterRender()
    {
        if(ComponentContext.IsConnected)
        {
            //adding scripts
        }
    }
}
```

How to make JS working with Blazor in suitable way ?
And how to fix that error ?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9613

Answer (score 5):

In your code sample, there are a couple of issues.

```
@inject IJSRuntime Js;

@functions {
    protected override async void OnAfterRender()
    {
        await Js.InvokeAsync<object>("addScriptFile","~/js/myFile.js");
    }
}
```

Firstly, you should use `code` not `functions`. `Code` is specific to Blazor components, `functions` is used for Razor Pages and MVC.

Secondly, never use `async void` in Blazor, the exception to the rule would be to run async code in an event handler. See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for more info.

Thirdly, you have the `~` character at the start of your script location. This character doesn’t work with Blazor (and is pretty pointless anyway in my opinion), it’s only valid with MVC and Razor Pages. If you want to load a script from the root of your application then just use a `/`, if you want to load it from a relative location then don’t prefix the location with anything.

So with all that said, I think your code should look like this.

```
@inject IJSRuntime Js;
@inject IComponentContext ComponentContext

@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync()
    {
        if (!ComponentContext.IsConnected)
        {
            return;
        }

        await Js.InvokeAsync<object>("addScriptFile","/js/myFile.js");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :)
Firstly, ```@code``` has no intellisense, it is just plain text. Maybe I didn't mention that I am working on VS 2019 community **NOT PREVIEW**. 
Secondly, in some cases I have to use some awaited functions, so I need to use async. 
Thridly, I have removed ~, and I think this is not a problem because the file has been added to the page successfully, but the problem happening when the page got reloaded

Comment: You need to be using VS Preview for Blazor development. There are features which are only available in preview right now. Using async is not the issues it’s the fact you have the return type as void and not Task.

Comment: Ok, I think first step I have to download VS preview and use it then I will see.

Comment: I found the solution. My mistake was inject IJSRuntime one time in the MainLayout and stored it in a static variable to use it everywhere. Now when the IJSRuntime has been injected in each component, the problem solved. Thank you for your help :)